# Partial match to regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have several lines that look like this:

```
test=['S123X_ILL_BE_BACK','BA34_HASTA_LA_VISTA_BABY','JA3841_SARAH','J102_CONNOR']
```

And I am trying to retrieve all that comes after the first `\_`. In my regex I am trying

```
 import re
 [re.sub(".+\_(.+)","\g<1>",gg) for gg in test]
```

but this truncates to the last word. How can I get

```
 ['ILL_BE_BACK','HASTA_LA_VISTA_BABY','SARAH','CONNOR']
```

Comment: [`[gg.partition("_")[-1] if "_" in gg else gg for gg in test]`](http://rextester.com/UHNIF62476)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to make the first `+` not greedy:

```
[re.sub(".+?\_(.+)","\g<1>",gg) for gg in test] # note the ?
```

returns:

```
['ILL_BE_BACK', 'HASTA_LA_VISTA_BABY', 'SARAH', 'CONNOR']
```

The `?` after the `+` makes the `+` none-greedy, so it consum only as much as needed:

```
re.match('.*',"abcdefgh") # finds 'abcdefgh' (the entire string)
re.match('.*?',"abcdefgh") # finds '' (an empty string)
re.match('.+',"abcdefgh") # finds 'abcdefgh' (the entire string)
re.match('.+?',"abcdefgh") # finds 'a' (only the first character)
re.match('.+?f',"abcdefgh") # finds 'abcdef' (all characters till f)
```

This means your regex `.+\_(.+)` consumes everything till he gets just enough to match the rest `_(.+)` which is only the last part. If you change the regex to `.+?\_(.+)`, it will only consume till the first `_` and then stop.

Comment: I'm trying to understand it, but the online resources I've found didnt explain much. How does the `?` work?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without regex.

```
['_'.join(gg.split('_')[1:]) for gg in test]
```

Edit: for case with element without `_`.

```
['_'.join(gg.split('_')[('_' in gg):]) for gg in test]
```

Comment: It does not support items that do not contain `_`, it will remove an empty item.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a simpler regex here, and even a non-regex approach:

```
import re
test=['S123X_ILL_BE_BACK','BA34_HASTA_LA_VISTA_BABY','JA3841_SARAH','J102_CONNOR','SARAH']
print([gg.partition("_")[-1] if "_" in gg else gg for gg in test])
```

Here, the `partition` method will split at the first `_` and the last item is what you need. If `_` is missing, the whole item is returned.

A regex way:

```
print([re.sub(r'^[^_]*_', '', gg) for gg in test])
```

Here, `^[^_]*_` matches

- `^` - start of the string
- `[^_]*` - 0+ chars other than `_`
- `_` - a `_`

and the matches get removed.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cJPfa3/1).

See [this Python demo](http://rextester.com/ATWOVY63602)